# can't update fragment view after onCreate

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, view, fragment

I know that this is a common problem and I've read dozens of topics here but am still not able to find a solution.

My intention is to change the visibility of a button in a fragment after receiving a notification but I can't change it's layout after it is already created. I've also tried to set the visibility in the `onCreate()` method by using a boolean, but then I would need a way to refresh the fragment.

MainActivity.class

> ```
> package com.example.TestButton;
>
> import java.util.Calendar;
>
>
> import android.app.AlarmManager;
> import android.app.PendingIntent;
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
> import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
> import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
> import android.view.Menu;
> import android.view.MenuItem;
>
> public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
>
>   private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
>   private AlarmManager am;
>   private Calendar c;
>
>   @Override
>   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>       android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
>       Fragment bf = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.button_fragment);
>
>       FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
>       transaction.show(bf);
>       transaction.commit();
>
>       setNextButtonClick();
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>       // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
>       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
>       return true;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>       // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
>       // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
>       // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
>       int id = item.getItemId();
>       if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
>           return true;
>       }
>       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
>   }
>
>   private void setNextButtonClick() {
>       c = Calendar.getInstance();
>
>       c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
>       c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 29);
>       c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
>
>
>       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ButtonAlarmReceiver.class);
>       pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
>
>       am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
>       am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
>     }
>
>   public void handleButtonView() {
>       new ButtonFragment().showButton();
>   }
> }
> ```

ButtonFragment.class

> ```
> package com.example.TestButton;
>
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
> import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
> import android.view.LayoutInflater;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.view.ViewGroup;
> import android.widget.Button;
>
> public class ButtonFragment extends Fragment{
>
>   @Override
>   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
>           @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
>
>       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_fragment, container, false);
>
>       return view;
>   }
>
>   public void showButton() {
>       Button button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button); //Gives NullPointerException here!
>       button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>   }
>
>
> }
> ```

ButtonAlarmReceiver.class

> ```
> package com.example.TestButton;
>
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
>
>
> public class ButtonAlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{
>
>   @Override
>   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>       Intent service = new Intent(context, ButtonAlarmService.class);
>
>       startWakefulService(context, service);
>   }
>
>
>
> }
> ```

ButtonAlarmService.class

> ```
> package com.example.TestButton;
>
> import android.app.IntentService;
> import android.app.Notification;
> import android.app.NotificationManager;
> import android.app.PendingIntent;
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
>
> public class ButtonAlarmService extends IntentService{
>
>   private NotificationManager nm;
>
>   private Notification notification;
>
>   public ButtonAlarmService() {
>       super("Imma button!");
>   }
>
>   @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
>   @Override
>   protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
>       nm = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
>
>       Intent newIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
>       newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
>       PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, newIntent,
> ```
>
> PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
>
> ```
>       NotificationCompat.Builder notifBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
>       notification = notifBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle("Test
> ```
>
> Button").setContentText("You need to press the button!").build();
>
> ```
>       nm.notify(0, notification);
>
>       MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
>       ma.handleButtonView();
>
>       ButtonAlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
>   }
>
> }
> ```

Manifest

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     package="com.example.TestButton"
>     android:versionCode="1"
>     android:versionName="1.0" >
>
>     <uses-sdk
>         android:minSdkVersion="14"
>         android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
>
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
>
>     <application
>         android:allowBackup="true"
>         android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
>         <activity
>             android:name=".MainActivity"
>             android:label="@string/app_name" >
>             <intent-filter>
>                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>             </intent-filter>
>         </activity>
>
>         <service android:name=".ButtonAlarmService"
>                  android:enabled="true" />
>
>         <receiver android:name=".ButtonAlarmReceiver"/>
>     </application>
>
> </manifest>
> ```

Comment: You may want to read about communicating with a fragment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html.  You can store a reference to the button and then have a listener that is invoked when the notification is received and then hide the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call `new` on an `Activity`.  It must be created and managed by the system via an `Intent`.  The reason you're not seeing any changes it because from the system's perspective your `Activity` doesn't exist.  Since you're already setting up a `PendingIntent` for your own notification, just add it as an extra which your `MainActivity` extracts when it processes in `Intent` and set your button visibility via that mechanism.

Comment: How can I add it as an extra?

Comment: `newIntent.putExtra("your_extra_name", true)`.  I'd recommend using a `static final String` (constant) instead of a hardcoded string like I've shown here.  That way when your `Activity` extracts it you are using a common definition.